# How to remove a node from a directional graph without breaking the chain

Tags: networkx

I am trying to get rid of existing cycle by removing node 3 and adding it right after node 8. The problem is that when I remove node 3 the connection between node 2 and 4 is broken. How can I move node 3 without breaking this chain?

Here is a reference picture to better understand my problem:
[image]

Comment: add an edge from node 4 to node 2 before you remove node 3?

Comment: Yeah, that would be one way to do it. I was hoping there might be some built-in functionality to accomplish this more efficiently. What if I had 1M or more edges connected to it? The operation of recreating all of those edges in Python would be quite costly!